# Query is unable to match parts after "/" or parts within "()" in the data

Tags: sqlite

I have a search request written as

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('locker_data.db')

c = conn.cursor()

```
def search1(teacher):
    test = 'SELECT Name FROM locker_data WHERE Name or Email LIKE "%{0}%"'.format(teacher)
    data1 = c.execute(test)
    return data1

def display1(data1):
    Display1 = []
    for Name in data1:
        temp1 = str(Name[0])
        Display1.append("Name: {0}".format(temp1))
    return Display1

def locker_searcher(teacher):
    data = display1(search1(teacher))
    return data
```

This allows me to search for the row containing "Mr FishyPower (Mr Swag)" or "Mr FishyPower / Mr Swag" with a search input of "FishyPower". However, when I try searching with an input of "Swag", I am then unable to find the same row.

In the search below, it should have given me the same search results.

The database is just a simple 1x1 sqlite3 database containing 'FishyPower / Mr Swag'

[Search Error on 'Swag'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QEyx.png)

Edit: I technically did solve it by limiting the columns being searched to only 'Name' but I intended the code search both the 'Name' and 'Email' columns and output the results as long as the search in within either or both columns.

Edit2: SELECT Name FROM locker_data WHERE Email LIKE "%{0}%" or Name LIKE "%{0}%" was the right way to go.

Comment: In it's current form, this question is unanswerable.There is no indication what sqlite3 interface you are using and that sql (as written) will not return either of the rows described.  Remember, [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Understood, I have updated the question with more details. Picture of search not working included at the end.

Comment: I don't think "where name or email like" is a valid clause. It should probably be "where name like something or email like something".

Comment: @Aioros Thx man, that actually worked :v How did I not try that :v

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna guess that Mr. FishyPower's email address is something like `mrFishyPower@something.com`. The query is only comparing Email to teacher. If it was

```
WHERE Name LIKE "%{0}%"
OR Email LIKE "%{0}%"'
```

you would (probably) get the result you want.